# HTML5 Audio Player Issue

Tags: jquery, html, audio

i am creating a simple html5 player it works like this : 
there are "n" players on the page
users clicks on a play button and the play button becomes pause button(with toggleClass("pause-now") )
if user click on another play button , the previous playing audio should be stopped and it's button should become "play button"
i use this code below , everything works fine the only thing is when an audio is playing and user plays another audio the playing audio's button stays fixed and does not change while it should change to play button

```
<audio id="simpleplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>">
  <source src="<?php echo $ogg_play; ?>" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="<?php echo $mp3_play; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your Browser Does not Support Audio Players
</audio> 
<a class="play-now" title="Play Now" id="simpleplay<?php echo $player_no; ?>" rel="simpleplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>"></a>
<script>
    var audioplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?> = document.getElementById("simpleplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>");

    function pauseothers(){
        $('audio').each(function () {
            var myAudio = this;
            this.addEventListener('play', function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    var pla = $(this);
                    if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                        this.pause();
                        pla.next().toggleClass('pause-now');  
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
    $("#simpleplay<?php echo $player_no; ?>").click(function(){
        if (audioplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>.paused) {
            pauseothers();
            audioplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>.play();
        }
        else {
           audioplayer<?php echo $player_no; ?>.pause();
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('pause-now');  
    });
</script>
```

iv'e also set up a simple example in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/PzLcR/
the only problem with this code is , when an audio is playing and u click on another play button the previous audio's button doesn't change , please help!!

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle where all the javascript is in the javascript window, please?

Comment: here u go [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fcARN/1/)

Comment: but it doesn't work when i put javascripts in a window , i uploaded a simple html file [link](http://farscode.ir/up/new.zip) , thank u

Comment: The downloaded file doesn't work at all (I tried in both Chrome and Safari).  I recommend getting it to work in JSfiddle.  You may discover by the separation-of-javascript process what's causing your issue.